# PyMySql - Para que serve o .cursor()

Tags: mysql, python, banco-de-dados

Estou em aprendizado de banco de dados atraves do PyMySql no Python, porém muitos videos apenas fala como fazer mas não fala, porque fez... Queria perguntar para que serve o .cursor() em PyMySQL?

Comment: Após  criado o banco de dados faz o acesso utilizando o nome a senha e tbm o usuário O cursor em um banco de dados é utilizado para fazer acesso a banco de dados.com o cursor aberto faz insert update e delete

Answer (score -3):

Após a criação do banco de dados o que acontece é que o `.cursor` retorna um "novo cursor" no seu Data Base, ele serve para escrever, acrescentar, criar tabelas, editar tabelas e entre outras coisas, ele simplesmente te dá tudo que o Mysql pode oferecer no terminal(cli) com retorno é claro para o Python interpretar...